Propagate information from worker to master
The problem i want to solve is:

The script execution must return error code anytime tests fails
Each subsequent execution of the script must process only the data difference from the last execution

To achieve that I'm running a simple data quality pipeline through spark structured streaming:
df_stream = (
    spark.readStream.format("delta")
    .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
    .load(path_to_table_under_test)
)
stream = (
    df_stream.writeStream.foreachBatch(run_data_quality_tests)
    .trigger(availableNow=True)
    .option("checkpointLocation", spark_checkpoint_location)
    .start()
)
stream.awaitTermination()

The run_data_quality_tests method has a logics like this:
def run_data_quality_tests(df):
  tests_flag = True
  for i in test_suites:
    result = test_suite.test(df)
    if result is False:
      tests_flag=False
      break

  if test_flag is False:
    raise ValueError("Tests Failed")


This works as expected, however if any of the partitions contains the data which does not meet the DQ test requirements the whole streaming fails and checkpoint is not written.
Since I want structured streaming to always process the new elements I've decided to remove exception triggering from the test_function and instead detect the "silent" failures through accumulator
    fail_detector = spark.sparkContext.accumulator(0)
    df_stream = (
        spark.readStream.format("delta")
        .option("readChangeFeed", "true")
        .load(path_to_table_under_test)
    )
    stream = (
        df_stream.writeStream.foreachBatch(run_data_quality_tests)
        .trigger(availableNow=True)
        .option("checkpointLocation", spark_checkpoint_location)
        .start()
    )
    stream.awaitTermination()

    if fail_detector.value > 0:
     raise ValueError("Quality Tests failed")


and also updated the run_data_quality_tests
def run_data_quality_tests(df):
  global fail_detector

  tests_flag = True
  for i in test_suites:
    result = test_suite.test(df)
    if result is False:
      tests_flag=False
      break

  if test_flag is False:
    fail_detector +=1

Is it the correct approach for such a problem within spark? It feels a little hackish

Maybe creating a delta table for logging results is a solution.

Something to kept in mind is that in case of task failure. The same value can be written to accumulators multiple times. So you can’t depend on their value being exact, but only as an estimation.
